# Embedding issuu

Tags: web-services, api, frontend, issuu

I need to embed an [issuu](http://issuu.com/) document inside a website. The website administrator should be allowed to decide which document is displayed on the frontend.

This is an easy task, using the embed link on the issuu page. But I need to customize some options - for instance, disable sharing, set the dimensions and so on. I cannot rely on the administrators doing this process every time they need to change the document.

I can easily customize the issuu embed code to my taste, and all that I need is the document id. Unfortunately, the id is not included in the issuu page for the document. For instance, the id for [this random link](http://issuu.com/gruppotuo/docs/stilicone/1) happens to be `110209071155-d0ed1d10ac0b40dda80dad24166a76ee`, which is nowhere to be found, neither in the URL nor easily inside the page. You have to dig into the embed code to find it.

I thought the [issuu API](http://issuu.com/services/api/) could allow me to get a document id given its URL, but I cannot find anything like this. The closest match is the search API, but if I [search for the exact name of the document](http://search.issuu.com/api/2_0/document?q=stilicone/1) I get only one match for a **different** document!

> Is there some easy way to be able to embed a document only knowing its URL? Or an easy way for a non techie person to find a document id in the page?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I need to enable printing..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunate the only way for you to costomize is to pay for the service wich is 39$ for month =/.

You can force a fullscreen mode without ads by using

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">        
    <iframe src="YOUR ISSU EMBED" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:105%;width:105%;position:absolute;" height="100%" width="100%""></iframe>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can embed of course stacks but that isnt showed on Issuu site. This is code (its old code but it works):

```
<iframe src="http://static.issuu.com/widgets/shelf/index.html?folderId=FOLDERIDamp;theme=theme1&amp;rows=1&amp;thumbSize=large&amp;roundedCorners=true&amp;showTitle=true&amp;showAuthor=false&amp;shadow=true&amp;effect3d=true" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="200"></iframe>
```

FOLDERID is number of 36 chars that you get on address bar when you enter stacks (example: https://issuu.com/username/stacks/FOLDERID). When you replacing that in code you must paste 36 chars in this format 8-4-4-4-12 with - between chars. And voila its working.
You can change theme and other stuffs in code.

Comment: Very confused about the folderId. When you pointed out the format was all that changed it made perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

The Document ID is found in the HTML source of every document. It is in the og:video meta property.

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v2/IssuuReader.swf?mode=mini&amp;documentId=XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;pageNumber=0">
```

You can easily handle it by using the [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DomXPath](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domxpath.php) php classes.

Here is how-to using PHP:

```
//  Your document URL
$url = 'https://issuu.com/proyectotres/docs/proyecto_3_edicion_135';

//  Turn off errors, loads the URL as an object and then turn errors on again
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);   
$dom = DomDocument::loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

//  DomXPath helps find the <meta property="og:video" content="http://hereyoucanfindthedocumentid?documentId=xxxxx-xxxxxxx"/> 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$meta = $xpath->query("//html/head/meta[@property='og:video']");

//  Get the content attribute of the <meta> node and parse its query
$vars = [];
parse_str(parse_url($meta[0]->getAttribute('content'))['query'], $vars);

//  Ready. The document ID is here:
$docID = $vars['documentId'];

// You can print it:
echo $docID;
```

You can try it with the URL of your own Issu document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Issuu URL of your document to complete this iframe :

```
<iframe width="100%" height="283" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://e.issuu.com/issuu-reader3-embed-files/latest/twittercard.html?u=nantucketchamber&amp;d=program-update1&amp;p=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" span="" id="CmCaReT"></iframe>
```

You just need to replace "nantucketchamber" by a user name and "program-update1" by the file name in the Issuu URL

(for this example the URL is https://issuu.com/nantucketchamber/docs/program-update1)